# Probability that all 12 tickets received were given on Tuesday or Thursday

Tags: probability

I have a problem in solving the following task:

> Imagine there is a man who got 12 tickets because he was parking his car in a wrong place. All the tickets were given on Tuesday or on Thursday. What is the probability of this occurrence? We assume that the police have none special system (that means that the probability of getting a ticket is the same for every day of the week).

I spent a lot of time thinking about the correct solution but I haven't managed to do anything smart.
I figured out that the probability of a police control (and getting a ticket) must be equal to $\frac{1}{7}$ but unfortunately that's all.
I would appreciate any hints of tips.

Comment: Hint: What is the probability that the day one receives a single ticket is Tuesday or Thursday?

Comment: @Did think it's $\frac{13}{49}$ but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Why? How? After which computations? Come on...

Comment: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = 2 \frac{1}{7} - (\frac{1}{7})^2$ am I right?

Comment: No. I guess you are using $A$ for the event "The day they receive their single ticket is Tuesday" and $B$ for the event "The day they receive their single ticket is Thursday", right? But then, what is $A\cap B$?

Comment: @Did You're right! $A \cap B$ would be "The day they receive their single ticket is Tuesday and Thursday". That statement can't be true of course.

Comment: Yep. Now, the same with "12 tickets" instead of "one single ticket"...

Comment: @Did That makes $(\frac{2}{7})^{12}$! And that's the answer. Thank you! :)

Comment: Quite so. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I think the problem you are trying to solve is:

A man has been given 12 parking tickets.
Given that there is an equal chance of receiving a ticket on each day of the week, what is the probability that all tickets were received on either Tuesday or Thursday.

Based on this, the probability that any given ticket is given on a Tuesday or Thursday is $$P(X(i)=\text{Tuesday or Thursday}) = \dfrac{2}{7}$$.
So, assuming that all tickets are independently given, the probability that all 12 tickets were given on either a Tuesday or Thursday is $$(\dfrac{2}{7})^{12}$$

If the tickets are not independent, for example due to the fact that you could only get one ticket a day, then this is a more challenging problem and more information is needed regarding the time period that we are looking at.